# Trying to set up QoS on my router for my machine but it demands that I use a destination IP?

Tags: router, gaming, steam

So I'm trying to set QoS for my machine to steam and from what I've seen I should be fine with what I have now but it demands I have a destination ip, what do I do?

[image]

Comment: Here is a screen cap to the message http://puu.sh/pkVOQ.png , yes I have put my own public IP there but it is blocked so you do not see it

Comment: Firstly, do not add information through comments.  Instead edit your question.  I thought of editing it for you until I saw that this screen capture gives absolutely no useful information.  Did you try to put in Steam's IP address to see if it would accept it?

Comment: It was more of a visual thing to affirm I'm not a loony, considering it's not usefulness I won't edit it in but I will do that in the future. On the steam website it says this is all I need to add on to QoS https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711

Comment: Could the destination IP refer to your computer's local IP?

Comment: Should have the destination and the source Ip. The source I thought would be your local ip the computer and the Destination would be the IP the isp gave you.

Comment: Okay I think I figured it out with what you said network kingpin

Comment: If your issue is now resolved you should post the steps you took as an answer.